# Delphi,develop Browsers plugin

Tags: javascript, delphi, plugins, browser, detect

I want to develop a browser plugin via Delphi, to be installed with the application,

the purpose from this plugin is just to check via browser if my program is installed on users computers or not

using navigator.plugin function

```
     if (navigator.plugins["My Browser Plugin name"]) {
          alert('yes application installed');
     } else {
          alert('not installed redirect to download page');
     }
```

Please Help if anyone know how to develop this browser plugin on Delphi ??

Comment: Yes, we know. What is you specific question? Did you try to ask Google and examine the [result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI)?

Comment: i Want to know how we can develop this browser plugin in Delphi,  to be installed in user's PC during application setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are specific types of plugins according to the browsers you are targeting.
Internet Explorer uses ActiveX plugins, while Chrome, Firefox and others use NPAPI plugins.

Unfortunately you can't implement both types of plugin in the same Delphi project. You need one project for each implementation.

There's FireBreath, a C++ plugin framework you can use to build poweful browser plugins targetting all major browser platforms with the same code base. You could easily implement a function to check if your app is installed and deploy a FireBreah plugin compatible with IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc.

See: firebreath.org/display/documentation/Getting+Started

If you can't use C++, here are some useful Delphi examples on NPAPI and ActiveX plugins:

NPAPI: https://www.mozdev.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=2541

ActiveX: http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/master-delphi-7/content/LiB0126.html

NPAPI plugins are relatively simple to implement and register. For ActiveX you need a little bit more effort, but it's perfecly possible.

Comment: how to install NPDemo.dll because its not registrable dll ?

Comment: Check the Mozilla Wiki: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Plugins/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Development_Overview#Windows_Installation_Using_the_Registry

Once you install an NPAPI plugin in windows registry it will be available for all browsers that use NPAPI, like Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.